# cs50: pset6: Why both of these while loops don't work as expected?

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, cs50

Having trouble figuring out why these loops don't work as expected. I want the user to be entering a string (height) and if it contains characters, request a height again until certain integers are typed.

First loop: Here. I'm expecting that if I put in a number from 1 until 8, the loop will break, but it doesn't! It keeps requesting the height.

```
height = input("What's the height?\n")
while type(height) != int or (height < 1 or height >= 9):
    height = input("What's the height?\n")
```

Second loop: Expecting the same. Loop doesn't break, keeps asking for height.

```
while True:
    height = input("What's the height?\n")
    if type(height) == int and (height >= 1 and height <= 8):
        break
```

Just got into Python but this doesn't seem to be a Python problem, more like something that I'm missing on while loops.

**EDIT**

Made it work finally. This worked like a charm.

```
while True:
height = input("What's the height?\n")
if not(height.isalpha()):
    if not(height.isspace()):
        if height != "":
            height = int(height)
            if height >= 1 and height <= 8:
                break
```

Comment: the type of height is always a string here

Answer (score 0):

This will address your query:

```
height = input("What's the height?\n")
while not(height.isnumeric()) or (int(height) < 1 or int(height) >= 9):
    height = input("What's the height?\n")
```

Comment: I want my loop to be asking for a height again if the user enters characters. If I modify the code to take just ints, I get an error.

Comment: Okay I have edited the code to your query now

Comment: It didn't work unfortunately. I got a string to int error again.